# Select Timeout OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I got "select timeout" every time I start program with OpenCV.
About 1 hour ago everything worked well. I don't know, what's the reason for it. Please, help. 
OpenCV 2.4.1, Raspbian

Comment: I think a little bit more details (may be a few related log files) could be helpful.

Comment: It's kind of a "known issue". Make sure you've imported `highgui`, you have `ocl`, and cross your fingers.